# Size of minimal generating set of a module generated by columns of a diagonal matrix with extra structure

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit. Let $A \in R^{k \times k}$ be a diagonal matrix such that $A_{11} | A_{22} | \dots | A_{rr}$ for some $r \leq k$ and are non-zero, while $A_{ii}=0$ for all $i > r$. Here $A_{11} | A_{22}$ means that $A_{11}$ divides $A_{22}$ in $R$. Let $M$ be the $R$-module generated by the columns of $A$, which is a submodule of $R^{k}$.

I'm trying to establish that the minimal number of generators of $M$ is equal to $r$. I know this fails if we don't have the divisibility condition. For example if $R = \mathbb{Z}_{10}$, and $A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 5 \end{pmatrix}$, then $\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}$ is a generating set for the module $M$.

I was able to prove this statement when $r \leq 2$, but have not been able to extend to larger values of $r$. I just want to know if this is false or not, and if an easy counterexample is known.

If this result is known to be true (may be with added conditions imposed on the ring), any reference will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be a maximal ideal of $R$ containing $\operatorname{ann}(A_{rr})$. Then $M$ surjects onto $(M/\mathfrak{m})^r$ which is generated by $r$ elements over $R$ but not less.

Comment: Thanks. $R/m$ is a field & so this is a very elegant solution!